# angular doesn't update select elements with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular doesn't update select elements with the contents of ng-model. The binding is single way only select->model. How can I make changes in the model propagated to the view ?

template:

```
<select class="gu2" name="coverDuration" ng-model="creditLimit.coverDuration" required="required">
   <option ng-value="90" selected="selected">90 days</option>
   <option ng-value="180">180 days</option>
</select>
just to check: {{creditLimit.coverDuration}}
```

controller:

```
app.controller('CreditLimitDetailsController', function ( $scope, creditLimit /* ... */ ) {
    // creditLimit.coverDuration can be 90 or 180.
    // I use a service to store the values between successive instanciations
    $scope.creditLimit = creditLimit;
}
```

In this exemple, the select stays with no option select, whereas the check shows 90.

Comment: Have a look at [ngOptions](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select). This might make things a lot easier for you.

Comment: I see a lot of answer with ngOptions, but this seems overkill and confusive for just two static options :/. Seriously, how can such a simple thing not be included in angular ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.creditLimit = {}; //needs to be initialized
  $scope.creditLimit.coverDuration = 90;
});
```

and use

```
value=""
```

instead

```
ng-value=""
```

<kbd>[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQk6mwyPR3a1GvNpFpDa?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: it does not work for me(chrome 31.0.1650.63), which browser are you using ?

Comment: @BiAiB I am on 31.0.1650.63 too. I made a little edit. It works now. Use value instead ng-value.

Comment: that worked, while keeping ng-value. I need the value to be an integer because it will then be json serialized and the deseralizer won't allow strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `ngOptions` then just use [`ngSelected`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSelected) instead of `selected`:

```
<option ng-value="90" ng-selected="true">90 days</option>
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27a6V/)</kbd>

Comment: I edited the question. `coverDuration` is variable and can be 90 or 180 (in fact it's fed by this select among different instances of this controller). I think I could work around your example with `ng-selected=" creditLimit.coverDuration==90 "`

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to blur the elemenet after selection, this is browser dependent